# C++ Registry pattern implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns, template

I created a template registry class. It supports custom factory functions and custom constructors. Any kind of feedback is welcome (style, performance, bugs)

registry.hpp:

```
#ifndef REGISTRY_HPP
#define REGISTRY_HPP

//STL
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

template<typename Key>
class RegistryConstructionError : public std::exception
{
public:
    RegistryConstructionError(const Key &key)   :key(key){}

    const char *what()const throw(){return "Undefined key";}
    const Key key;
};

template<typename Base, typename Key, typename... Args>
class Registry
{
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> (*FactoryFunc)(Args... args);

    Registry() = default;
    ~Registry() = default;

    template<typename Derived>
    void registerClass(const Key &key);
    void registerFactory(const Key &key, const FactoryFunc factory);

    std::unique_ptr<Base> construct(const Key &key, Args... args);

private:
    template<typename Derived>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> constructDerived(Args... args);

    std::unordered_map<Key, FactoryFunc> m_map;

public:
    typedef RegistryConstructionError<Key> ConstrError;
};

#include "registry.tpp"

#endif // REGISTRY_HPP
```

registry.tpp:

```
template<typename Base,
        typename Key,
        typename... Args>
template<typename Derived>
void Registry<Base, Key, Args...>::registerClass(const Key &key)
{
    m_map[key] = &constructDerived<Derived>;
}

template<typename Base,
        typename Key,
        typename... Args>
void Registry<Base, Key, Args...>::registerFactory(const Key &key, const FactoryFunc factory)
{
    m_map[key] = factory;
}

template<typename Base,
        typename Key,
        typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<Base> Registry<Base, Key, Args...>::construct(const Key &key, Args... args)
{
    try{
        return m_map.at(key)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range &e)
    {
        throw ConstrError(key);
    }
}

template<typename Base,
        typename Key,
        typename... Args>
template<typename Derived>
std::unique_ptr<Base> Registry<Base, Key, Args...>::constructDerived(Args... args)
{
    return std::make_unique<Derived>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example how you are using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good stuff!

I definitely see a few improvements you could make here:

### Prefer using std::function to function pointers

There is a tiny bit more overhead invovled, but the extra flexibility is well worth it.

```
using FactoryFunc = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>(Args...)>;
```

Another advantage is that it lets you get rid of `constructDerived` entirely, and replace it with a nice lambda in `registerClass`.

### Nitpick: registerClass should invoke registerFactory.

Since `registerClass` is just a specialization of registerFactory, it should invoke it instead of reimplementing it. This is preferable because having a single point of entry makes refactorings like adding logging or debug monitoring a lot less error-prone.

### Prefer `using` instead of `typedef`

The semantics of type alisases are just a lot more legible that way.

### Wrong function definition for forwarding args

If you want to use forwarding as you do, construct needs to be declared in a way to use universal references, like so:

```
template<typename... CtrArgs>
std::unique_ptr<Base> construct(const Key &key, CtrArgs&&... args)
```

Otherwise, your `std::forward<>` call is useless and might as well be a `std::move`.

### Personal opinion: The custom exception type is not necessary here.

Letting the out_of_range exception bubble up is perfectly acceptable here, and lets your code be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! I implemented most of your points now. Capturing values in factories is very neat - didn't think of that.